# How to avoid storing fields with null in JSONB data type

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

How to avoid storing fields with null value while storing into postgres JSONB data type

This is the existing code for conversion, how to make it extensible but retain the structure as well

```
public class JsonbConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, Object> details) {
        String value = null;

        try {
            if (details == null || details.isEmpty()) {
                return value;
            }

            value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(details);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            log.error("unable to convert details to db {}", details, jpe);
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        Map<String, Object> value = null;

        try {
            if (dbData == null) {
                return value;
            }

            value = objectMapper.readValue(dbData, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("unable to convert details to entity {}", dbData, ioe);
        }

        return value;
    }

}
```

The stored value is:

```
{"categories": [{"name": "News", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}, {"name": "UK News", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}, {"name": "Crime", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}, {"name": "Dogs", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}, {"name": "Parenting advice", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}, {"name": "Pets", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}, {"name": "Police", "label": null, "taxonomyUri": null}]}
```

Comment: Why don't you just update the column have null values with jsonb_strip_nulls() function? Maybe you can create an SP and after all inserts, you can call this SP to strip null values from data.

Comment: How to avoid this while storing the data inside database on the above converter

Comment: I assume this is a Jackson `ObjectMapper`? It should omit null fields if you set `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may change your JsonbConverter to filter out null values from the MapString, Object> before converting it to JSON in order to prevent storing fields with null values in a JSONB data type in PostgreSQL. Here is an updated converter that performs what you want.
in this code the convertToDatabaseColumn method only includes non-null values in the output JSON and filters out null values from the input details map.
The JSON is changed back into a MapString, Object> using the convertToEntityAttribute function.

Here is the revised code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

@Converter
public class JsonbConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, Object> details) {
        try {
            if (details == null || details.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            // Create an ObjectNode to hold non-null values
            ObjectNode node = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : details.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                    JsonNode valueNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(entry.getValue());
                    node.set(entry.getKey(), valueNode);
                }
            }

            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        } catch (IOException jpe) {
            log.error("unable to convert details to db {}", details, jpe);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            if (dbData == null) {
                return null;
            }

            JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(dbData);

            // Convert the JSON to a Map<String, Object>
            Map<String, Object> value = objectMapper.convertValue(node, Map.class);

            return value;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("unable to convert details to entity {}", dbData, ioe);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works :)